# Java EE JAXRS: Portable way to marshell / un-marshell JSON with custom property names in API

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, apache-tomee

I am working on a Java EE 8 project. I am using Eclipse Photon as my development environment and WildFly 13 as my local development server. The problem is, the input/output JSON we have to deal with is having property names in **PascalCase** instead of **camelCase**. For example:

```
{
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 24
}
```

This format is working perfectly fine when used as an input to JAX-RS API. But, we need to facilitate this one instead:

```
{
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Age": 24
}
```

Also, we need to generate output in following format:

```
{
    "Status": 1,
    "Msg": "success"
}
```

There is got to be a way (like @JsonProperty) which lets you to customize property names.

Comment: Are you using the `-Dee8.preview.mode=true` system property when starting WildFly 13? Also WildFly 14.0.0.Final is out and Java EE 8 certified.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins no I am not using any flags. Thanks for the update. Strange thing is, eclipse didn't show me   that version, when I chose JBoss / Wildfly to run the application on.

Comment: For WildFly 13 you'd need to use the `-Dee8.preview.mode=true` flag or use `-c standalone-ee8.xml` when starting WildFly.

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly uses RESTEasy JAX-RS implementation which is built on top of Jackson. You can use Jackson specific annotations in your project if your target supported application server is Wildfly. If you're using Maven to build your deployment you can add Jackson as a provided dependency (just like jee api jars)

You could use JAXB annotations instead and configure Jackson used by RESTEasy to use them but that would only avoid pulling in Jackson as compile time dependency, your bundle will still depend on Jackson

Alternatively you can pull in Jackson explicitly as a runtime dependency and write message body readers and writers if server portability is important to you